# gsub for no square brackets or backslashes

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-5, gsub

I'm currently retrieving this back

`":root{--[{\"name\":\"--font\",\"value\":\"Arial\"},{\"name\":\"--bg\",\"value\":\"black\"}]:;}"`

I want this same output but with not backslashes or square brackets.

I've done `gsub(/\[/,'')` but it's not getting rid of the right square bracket. I know adding a right bracket after the left will mean something totally different with regex.

Comment: Try: gsub(\[|\]|\\, '')

Comment: Use `s = s.gsub(/[\]\[]/,'')`. Also, there are no backslashes in your *string*, there are backslashes in your string literal.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is it not opposite to what user asked for ?

Comment: @CodeManiac Yeah, edited.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `gsub(/[\[\\\]]/,'')` i tried this but i don't know why it is not replacing `\\` when i try to check in tester it is matching properly. link https://repl.it/repls/WarmheartedLeanBoards

Comment: @CodeManiac There are no backslashes in the `str = ":root{--[{\"name\":\"--font\",\"value\":\"Arial\"},{\"name\":\"--bg\",\"value\":\"black\"}]:;}"` string, they are only used in the double quoted string literal to introduce `"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh yeah just now noticed those are just backslashes for string literal. i was breaking my head from last 15 minutes :p

Comment: This is what i'm retrieving back from the JSON in postman.

Answer (score -1):

**You can try this mate**

**Well as @wiktor mentioned there are no backslashes in your string.Those are backslashes in your string literal.in case you don't have any backslashes `[\[\]]` this will be enough.**

```
Regex Pattern -> [\[\\\]]


str.gsub(/[\[\\\]]/,'')
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/WarmheartedLeanBoards)